# BizTalk and Enterprise Single Sign-On Best Practices?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2

I developed a BizTalk 2010 application that receives files from a ftp server, elaborates these files and sends them to another ftp server.
About Receive step, authentication is made using ESSO. I created two Affiliate Application, one for each ftp server storing credentials.
In Send step I created a method in a C# class library that is responsible for SSO ticket issuing. So before the send shape, orchestration calls the IssueSSOTicket method that returns an SSO ticket and it attaches it to the message using BTS.SSOTicket context property.
Everything works fine, but sometimes I get the error: A message sent to adapter "FTP" on send port "SendPortName" with URI "ftp://[ipaddress]:[port]/[path]/%SourceFileName%" is suspended.  Error details: A failure occurred when retrieving the SSO ticket.

Someone knows if there are some best practices in order to manage this scenario?
Thanks!

Massimo

Comment: Just curious why you use SSO here? Is this part of a bigger process where you need to maintain the caller's identity? 

Also assuming you have to use SSO then you need logging in your class library to give more information, on the surface I would "guess" that the identity is not mapped or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the problem locally, then you should be able to debug your custom assembly code that issues the SSO ticket by attaching to the BTSNTSvc process.

Here is a nifty post that describes how to attach Visual Studio's debugger to the BizTalk process and figure out which BizTalk process to attach to (if you have more than one): http://biztalkmessages.vansplunteren.net/2010/01/05/retrieve-the-btsntsvc-exe-pid-with-powershell/

If you can't do that, then how about posting the complete stack trace here?